# networkstream "cannot access a disposed object" when using newly created networkstream

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, networkstream

I have a few different methods which connect to a remote host, send a message, get a reply, and use the information. this has worked fine until i use two methods in the same instance of my connection class. in the example where i'm getting the error, i run the following method;

```
public string sendRequestAccountID(string siteID)
{
    //build message
    String response = String.Empty;

    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect(detailsHere);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.AutoFlush = false;

    writer.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    writer.Flush();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    List<XmlNode> nodeList = new List<XmlNode>();

    byte[] responseBytes = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        bytesRead = stream.Read(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            //handle message
        }
        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
            string finalResponse = stuffHereToSend;
            return finalResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

This sends fine, and returns a message as expected. However, if i then use the same instance of my connection class and use the following method;

```
public bool sendNewDevice(IDeviceInterface device)
{
    NetworkStream stream;
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    //build message
    String response = String.Empty;

    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect(detailsHere);
    stream = client.GetStream();

    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.AutoFlush = false;

    writer.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    writer.Flush();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    List<XmlNode> nodeList = new List<XmlNode>();

    byte[] responseBytes = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        bytesRead = stream.Read(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        { 
            //handle message
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error which reads "cannot access a disposed object" on;

```
 bytesRead = stream.Read(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
```

Although i thought that i'd newly just assigned the stream in the latest method. Is it trying to use the previously closed one? is there a way around this or something silly that i'm missing?

edit: is it something to with the clients not disposing correctly? the two methods are ran within a second of each other, maybe the second is trying to open before the first has closed?

Comment: Is there any code that's been removed from the method?  Perhaps something that disposes `writer` or `reader`?  When a `StreamWriter` or `StreamReader` is disposed, it disposes the underlying stream.

Comment: afraid not, i'm only disposing / closing at the end of each method. I've changed (while true) to (stream.CanRead) and this seems to have let it get past this point. I'm getting no response from a server now, so this must be another issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a `StreamWriter` (and reader) is closed or its `Dispose` method is called, it disposes the underlying stream.  Prior to .net 4.5 there really wasn't anything you could do about it, other than use something other than `StreamWriter` or write a class to wrap the `Stream` given to `StreamWriter` and ignore the call to `Dispose`.  in .NET 4.5, there is an overload you can use to tell the `StreamWriter` not to dispose the stream you give it.  eg: new `StreamWriter(stream,  StreamWriter.UTF8NoBOM, 1024, false)`

You could try using a wrapped stream to ignore the close (calling `new StreamWriter(new NonDisposableStreamWrapper(stream))`):

```
public class NonDisposableStreamWrapper : Stream
{
    private Stream wrappedStream;

    public NonDisposableStreamWrapper(Stream wrappedStream)
    {
        this.wrappedStream = wrappedStream;
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        wrappedStream.Flush();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return wrappedStream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        wrappedStream.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return wrappedStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        wrappedStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return wrappedStream.CanRead; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return wrappedStream.CanSeek; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return wrappedStream.CanWrite; }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return wrappedStream.Length; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { return wrappedStream.Position; }
        set { wrappedStream.Position = value; }
    }
}
```