# NetworkStream closed when sending many Protobuf messages

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net, networkstream

I use protobuf-net and .NET's TCPClient & NetworkStream for the communication between one server and many clients. For sending messages I use the following method on both sides:

```
   public static bool WriteProtocolBufferToStream(System.IO.Stream stream, object protoBufObject)
    {            
            // ... check parameters ...                
            // ... Determine the 'fieldNumber' of the 'protoBufObject' via a helper dictionary ...  
            if (fieldNumber > -1)
            {
                try { Serializer.NonGeneric.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, protoBufObject, ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle.Base128, fieldNumber); }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.Instance.Error("Exception: " + ex.Message);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Instance.Error("unknown message type");
                return false;
            }
            return true;            
    }
```

In small scenarios with only some clients and few messages, everything is fine. But I have problems in scenarios with about 40 clients and many exchanged messages. The messages are very small (containing 1 to 5 small strings) but it can occur that the server sends multiple (up to 200) of these messages at the same time.

The following exception is thrown after some time (some minutes to several hours):

```
ArgumentException: Cannot write to stream. Parameter name: dest
```

The source is protobuf-net's [ProtoWriter](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net/ProtoWriter.cs) class constructor. It throws this exception because the `CanWrite` property of the `NetworkStream` *dest* is false. My question is: Why does `CanWrite` change from true to false after a while? Could it have something to do with overflowing buffers (because I send many messages at the same time)? How could I fix it?

**EDIT:**

As @[Marc Gravell] already pointed out, the `NetworkStream` is disposed and therefore changes `CanWrite` from true to false. If I for instance try to access the `WriteTimeout` property of the *stream* object, I get this:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.GetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel optionLevel, SocketOptionName optionName)
    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.get_WriteTimeout()
    at Utilities.CommunicationHelper.WriteProtocolBufferToStream(NetworkStream stream, Object protoBufObject)
    ...
```

I'm still looking for something in my code, that could cause the disposal of the Socket. What else could cause the Socket beeing disposed after some time (several hours)?

Answer (score 3):

For `NetworkStream`, a little IL analysis shows that `CanWrite` defers to `m_Writeable`. In turn, `m_Writeable` becomes `false` in three ways:

- when it is disposed
- when it is created with the `access` parameter as `FileAccess.Read`
- when the `Writeable` property (`protected`) is assigned (I can see no evidence of this property actually being used in the framework, note)

So : if you are saying this happens on an already established `NetworkStream` that has been fine for a while, then the most likely answer is that it got disposed at some point, presumably due to being closed

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, now I have to find out why the NetworkStream is closed / disposed. I added some more log output to investigate this in a new test run.

Does protobuf-net Dispose() oder Close() a StreamReader or StreamWriter using the NetworkStream? According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11742029/1038088), that disposes the used NetworkStream.

Comment: @Rob iirc stream reader and writer do indeed close the underlying stream. From memory, protobuf-net does not - but I would have to check to be sure

Comment: Indeed, the `Socket` of the `NetworkStream` is disposed - see my **EDIT** in the question. Did you take a look at the StreamReader / StreamWriter usage in protobuf-net? Could protobuf-net be the cause of the disposal?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are exhausting the server's TCP/IP ports?

You don't mention which OS your server is running, but assuming it's 2008 server you have appx 16000 available ports (49152-65535). When you close  a connection, the port will stay in a TIME_WAIT status for 4 minutes before being available again. This means that if you have more than 16000 connections in less than 4 minutes, your server will start refusing connections.

When you experience the error, try running this command on the server:

```
netstat -p TCP -ano > netstat.txt
```

The number of lines in netstat.txt tells you the number of TCPv4 connections in the established or time_wait state.

You can tune this. Either by increasing the number of dynamic ports, reducing the time_wait interval or both.

To view your actual values:

- Time_wait (TcpTimedWaitDelay) (the default is 240, or 4 minutes if the value is not found)

  ```
  reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\TcpTimedWaitDelay
  ```
- Dynamic port range:

  ```
  netsh int ipv4 show dynamicportrange tcp
  ```

Some useful resources:

- [Port Exhaustion and You (or, why the Netstat tool is your friend)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/10/29/port-exhaustion-and-you-or-why-the-netstat-tool-is-your-friend.aspx)
- [How to tune the TCP/IP stack for high volume of web requests](http://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/6956/how-to-tune-the-tcp-ip-stack-for-high-volume-of-web-requests/)
- [Avoiding TCP/IP Port Exhaustion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610%28v=bts.20%29.aspx)
- [The default dynamic port range for TCP/IP has changed in Windows Vista and in Windows Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;929851)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems to have nothing to do with port exhaustion. My machine is a 2008 server and only about 50 of the 16384 ports are in use.

Comment: I can see no evidence of port exhaustion here. Nothing at all seems to point to that. The message certainly does not. Not only is this guesswork, it is outright unlikely to be the reason.

Comment: You don't mention it, but are you using threads? Just guessing since the information you provide is a bit sparse :-)

Comment: @Dag: Yes, I use threads. In the current version I `lock()` everything inside the `WriteProtocolBufferToStream()` method. The problem still occurs. So, it shouldn't be a threading problem.

Comment: @usr The creation and disposal of sockets is not shown and can possibly leak/incorrect error handling during creation, errors seems to occur when traffic increases (though the exact volume is not known). How can you eliminate port exhaustion as a possible reason based on the original question?

Comment: Ok, so all use of the networkstream instance you pass to the method is guaranteed to be synchronized? Except testing the code on a single thread just to be 100% sure, I'm out of ideas I'm afraid.